# Gathering ofono incoming call status in HTML page by XMLHTTPRequest

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest, dbus

I want to send a POST request to monitor-ofono.py to receive back the incoming call status & number, I successfully send a phone number to dial-number.py using XMLHTTPRequest.

HTML codes

```
<p id="strData"></p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var link = "http://0.0.0.0/cgi-bin/monitor-ofono.py";
    var Ofono = new XMLHttpRequest();
    Ofono.open("POST", link, true);
    Ofono.onreadystatechange = function ()
       {
        if(Ofono.readyState === 4) {
          if(Ofono.status === 200 || Ofono.status == 0){
               var res = Ofono.responseText;
               document.getElementById('strData').innerHTML = res;
            }
        }
}
    Ofono.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    Ofono.send(null);
</script>
```

monitor-ofono.py code (Below are the amended codes to make the question short)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gi.repository import GLib

import sys
import cgi
import dbus
import dbus.mainloop.glib
from gi.repository import GObject
import traceback
import json

sys.stderr = sys.stdout
print('Content-Type: text/plain\n\n')
print(json.dumps('Loading..'))

def property_changed(name, value, path, interface):
    iface = interface[interface.rfind(".") + 1:]
    print(str(json.dumps(pretty(value))))

def added(name, value, member, path, interface):
    iface = interface[interface.rfind(".") + 1:]
    print(str(json.dumps(pretty(value))))
```

I tried that way and was unable to get any data.
I appreciate any help hints.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully solved it by sending POST request to the server and be catch up by to call a function to gather the incoming calls status and send back the result by JSON to the client.